# BigQuery optimalization of the query CASE when

Tags: google-bigquery, case, mismatch, with-clause

I am trying to optimalize my query.

I will share it based on "books" example : My case is :

There are the same categories for books and library with paricular CODES

| Category | Code category |
| --- | --- |
| fantasy | fan |
| fiction | fic |
| biography | bio |

What i need to do :

1. categorize Books to particular codes based on their names
2. categorize data for "library codes" based on their names
3. Check if books from particular category fall into same category as library category

I have data like this

| `Book names` | `library` |
| --- | --- |
| `A Game of Thrones - fantasy` | `//AA/Project/Biography/shelf/blablabio` |
| `A Game of Thrones - fantasy` | `//AA/Project/Fantasy/hhhh/fan` |
| `Fan.The Lord of rings` | `//AA/Project/biography-123/123` |
| `Fan.The Lord of rings` | `//AA/Project//Fantasy/bio` |
| `Freddy Mercury.biography` | `//AA/Project/biography/123fin` |
| `Steve Jobs.bio` | `//AA/Project/fantasy555/567` |
| `The Handmaid's Tale.fic` | `//AA/Project/fiction/890bio` |
| `Robinson Crusoe.novel` | `//AA/Project/fin/555fin` |

So at the end i need to have logic IF Book Names contains same code as library it is fine and just list down Book names that have mismatches with library so here is my proposal of the query

```
With book_part as (
SELECT distinct
Book_names, 
library 
(CASE
when lower(Book_names) like '%fan%' then 'fan'
when Book_names like '%fic%'then 'fic'
when Book_names like '%bio%' then 'bio'
end ) as BOOK_code,
SPLIT(REPLACE(library, '/', ''),'/')[SAFE_OFFSET(2)] as Shelf,
FROM `table_name`),

with library_part (
Book_names, 
BOOK_code,
(CASE
when library like '%fan%' then 'fan'
when library like '%fic%'then 'fic'
when library like '%bio%' then 'bio'
end) as LIBRARY_CODE
from book_part)

Select *
from 
where BOOK_code = LIBRARY_CODE
```

and based on this I should get results of all mismatches of the codes :

| `Book names` | `BOOK_CODE` | `library` | `Shelf` | `LIBRARY_CODE` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `A Game of Thrones - fantasy` | `fan` | `//AA/Project/Biography/shelf/blablabio` | `Biography` | `bio` |
| `Fan.The Lord of rings` | `fan` | `//AA/Project/biography-123/123` | `biography-biography-123` | `bio` |
| `Steve Jobs.bio` | `bio` | `//AA/Project/fantasy555/567` | `fantasy555` | `fan` |
| `Robinson Crusoe.novel` | `null` | `//AA/Project/fin/555fin` | `fin` | `fin` |

Described above with example

Comment: Firstly, there are two `WITH` keywords in your SQL, it should only be declared once for your first CTE definition.

Answer (score 0):

Please tell us why you need to optimize your query. For readability, a sub Select with an unnest looks better. You can also may create an UDF with this code.

```sql
WITH
 tbl AS (
 SELECT *
 FROM UNNEST(["Book fan fun"," Book bio fun", "BIOlogy Book"]) a)

SELECT
 *,
 (SELECT REPLACE(ANY_VALUE( IF (lower(a) LIKE test,test,NULL)),"%","") FROM UNNEST(["%fan%","%bio%","%fic%"]) AS test ) as tag,
 (SELECT ANY_VALUE( IF (regexp_contains(lower(a), '('||test||')'),test,NULL)) FROM UNNEST(["fan","bio","fic"]) AS test ) as tag2,
 (SELECT ANY_VALUE( IF (regexp_contains(lower(a), '('||test.tag||')'),test.descr,NULL)) 
  FROM UNNEST([struct("fan" as tag,"fantasy" as descr),struct("bio","biography"),struct("fic","fiction")]) AS test ) as tag3,
FROM
 tbl
```

However, your `bio` tag will trigger on words in the title such as `BIOlogy`.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I want to optimalize query because i have some more codes to match. So from the naming I need to take part of it and catagorize it to particular buckets. I was thinking that adding more and more when book name like 'XXX" then XXX will raise issues.